# Mutable version of the filter function to filter results in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function called renderExercises which I call in my render function. renderExercises returns an array of ExercisesChoose components.

```
renderExercises() {
    const {selectedType} = this.state;
    const allExercises = this.props.exercises;

    let exercisesToRender = [];

    if (selectedType !== 'all') {
      exercisesToRender = allExercises[selectedType];
    } else {
      exercisesToRender = Object.values(allExercises)
        .reduce((array, subarray) => array.concat(subarray), [])
        .sort();
    }

    return exercisesToRender.map((exercise) => {
      return (
        <ExercisesChoose
          key={exercise}
          name={exercise}
        />
      )
    })
  }
```

So far this works. However I also want to filter based on search text if the user has entered this text.

This isn't working as filter can't be called on the existing array exercisesToRender.

```
    if (typeof this.searchText !== 'undefined') {
      const searchText = this.searchText.value;
      // This is not working 
      exercisesToRender.filter(item => {
        return item.includes(searchText);
      });
    }
```

What is the solution to this? Is there a sort method that allows for mutation? If so, is this advisable to use?

This is my current solution which works but is pretty ugly:

```
renderExercises() {
    const {selectedType} = this.state;
    const allExercises = this.props.exercises;

    let exercisesToRender = [];

    if (selectedType !== 'all') {
      exercisesToRender = allExercises[selectedType];
    } else {
      // Combine all the different exercise groups into a single array
      exercisesToRender = Object.values(allExercises)
        .reduce((array, subarray) => array.concat(subarray), [])
        .sort();
    }

    let render = [];

    if (typeof this.searchText !== 'undefined') {
      const searchText = this.searchText.value;
      render = exercisesToRender.filter(item => {
        return item.includes(searchText);
      });
    } else {
      render = exercisesToRender;
    }

    return render.map((exercise) => {
      return (
        <ExercisesChoose
          key={exercise}
          name={exercise}
        />
      )
    })
  }
```

This is what my exercises object looks like:

```
this.props.exercises = [
  legs:["Squat", "Power squats", "Burpees"]
  pull:["Pull up", "Chin up", "Dumbbell curl", "Horizontal row"]
  push:["Push up", "Bench press", "Dumbbell bench press", "Mountain climbers"]
  cardio: ["Running high knees", "Plank", "Crunches", "Skipping"]
]
```

Comment: I believe you should add the list of exercises to the component's state. Then, in a class method save the current state to a variable, filter that variable, then call setState() and overwrite the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My strategy for this case would be:

1. `reduce` to filter exercises by `type`
2. `filter` them by `searchText`
3. `sort`
4. `map` to render

Final result:

```
renderExercises() {
  const { selectedType } = this.state
  const { exercises: allExercises }  = this.props

  return Object
    .keys(allExercises)
    .reduce((result, key) => {
      if (selectedType === 'all' || key === selectedType) {
        return [
          ...result,
          ...allExercises[key],
        ]
      }

      return result
    }, [])
    .filter(exercise => searchText ? exercise.includes(searchText) : true)
    .sort()
    .map(exercise =>
      <ExercisesChoose
        key={exercise}
        name={exercise}
      />
    )
}
```

```js
const exercises = {
  legs:["Squat", "Power squats", "Burpees"],
  pull:["Pull up", "Chin up", "Dumbbell curl", "Horizontal row"],
  push:["Push up", "Bench press", "Dumbbell bench press", "Mountain climbers"],
  cardio: ["Running high knees", "Plank", "Crunches", "Skipping"],
}

const filterExercises = (type, searchText) => {
  return Object
    .keys(exercises)
    .reduce((result, key) => {
      if (type === 'all' || key === type) {
        return [
          ...result,
          ...exercises[key],
        ]
      }

      return result
    }, [])
    .filter(exercise => searchText ? exercise.includes(searchText) : true)
    .sort()
    .join(', ')
}
  
console.log('All exercises:', filterExercises('all', ''))
console.log('All (up):', filterExercises('all', 'up'))
console.log('Push:', filterExercises('push', ''))
console.log('Push (press):', filterExercises('push', 'press'))
```

Comment: Ive updated my question showing what this.props.exercises looks like.

Comment: Im working through your code. .keys(allExercises) returns this: ["push", "legs", "pull", "cardio"]

Comment: But the reduce function returns ["p", "u", "s", "h"] so I think the code is incorrect at this point.

Comment: @Evans I forgot to add the `[]` as initial value in the `reduce` method :)

Answer (score 0):

Ive expanded slightly on mersocarlin's answer as I was getting some false results from searchText, but essentially his logic does work.

```
renderExercises() {
    const {selectedType} = this.state;
    const allExercises = this.props.exercises;

    let searchText = false;
    if (this.searchText && this.searchText.value.length > 0) {
      searchText = this.searchText.value.toLowerCase();
    }

    return Object
      .keys(allExercises)
      .reduce((result, key) => {
        if (selectedType === 'all' || key === selectedType) {
          return [
            ...result,
            ...allExercises[key]
          ]
        }
        return result
      }, [])
      .filter(exercise => searchText ? exercise.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) : true)
      .map((exercise) => {
        let active = false;
        if (this.props.chosenExercise === exercise) {
          active = true;
        }
        return (
          <ExercisesChoose
            key={exercise}
            name={exercise}
            active={active}
            setNumber={this.props.number}
            updateValue={this.props.updateValue}
          />
        )
      })
  }
```

Comment: You can set `active` directly on `ExercisesChoose` component. Simply set `active={this.props.chosenExercise === exercise}` :)